# Почему у std::deque нет метода capacity()?

Tags: c++

Не понятно, почему у std::deque нет методов capacity() и reserve(), при этом метод shrink_to_fit() - имеется.

У std::string, std::vector, std::list - есть, а вот у очереди нет. За что так обделили ?

Как то это совсем не понятно.

Comment: У std::list нет capacity и reserve. Внутри deque обычно это просто `std::list<std::vector<T>>` (но не факт)

Comment: @KoVadim, на какая бы реализация не была бы внутри, емкость по любому есть - элементы же в чем то хранятся. shrink_to_fit() - то имеется.

Comment: Да, думаю там емкость есть, но что оно что оно даст - не знаю